# Excel "smart" autocomplete based on regex (new feature?)

Tags: excel

I have Microsoft Excel Professional Plus 2013.

I was just typing down a couple of strings, and then, out of the blue, Excel "smart predicted" the rest of the column I was going to type.

I've been using Excel for over a decade and never seen an AutoFill like this. It basically looks at all of the surrounding columns (not just the immediate left one), identifies a regex, and populates it down.

I've attached an image to show its predictions.

[image]

It's not entirely accurate, but if I type "ma", then it is completely accurate by looking at the column immediately to the left.

[image]
[image]

I have simply never seen this feature before (but I really really like it). Does this feature have a name?

I don't believe I have any plugins that are doing this, but here they are just to double check.

[image]

Would definitely be curious to hear when this feature came about, and how it got installed on my machine (ie. auto-push updates by Microsoft)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It is called Flash Fill, available after Excel 2013.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/using-flash-fill-in-excel-3f9bcf1e-db93-4890-94a0-1578341f73f7